# How to kill all thread are running in c language?

Tags: c, multithreading, kill

I had some thread are running in my program. I want to kill them. What can I do? In addition, I want to get thread current which is running in program.

Comment: If they are running chase them and kill them, kill them all.No mercy!

Comment: On a serious note, can you present your question more clearly and with more details?

Comment: How can you kill what and how?  Do you want the program to kill its own threads?  Why can't you type Ctrl-C?  How about the `kill` command?  What is it you want?

Comment: Call your OS 'ExitProcess' API, whatever that is.   That will request the OS to kill all your threads.

Comment: Which OS? Which functions do you use to create the threads? Do you want to Signal the threads that they shall terminate or do you want to forcible kill the threads? You want to get the thread that is running in your program? Which one of them, multiple threads might run in parallel!?

Answer (score 1):

You have to find out where you created the thread somewhere like [`pthread_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html)`(&pid....)` `pid` is the thread handle. In order to kill them you will need [`pthread_kill`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_kill.html)

To check which thread is running currently you can use [`pthread_self`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_self.html)

Comment: Or better still, send a message to the thread (via a pipe, for instance) requesting it to return gracefully.

Comment: @James I am a newbie to threads. Are you suggesting usage of `pthread_cancel` ? or do you mean using semaphores etc to indicate the thread it must terminate? and wait for it using `pthread_join`?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very much clear here. Moreover its better to terminate the thread with 
[pthread_exit()](http://man.yolinux.com/cgi-bin/man2html?cgi_command=pthread_exit). But if still you want to kill the threads you can use [pthread_kill()](http://man.yolinux.com/cgi-bin/man2html?cgi_command=pthread_kill) but do check its return value as it may fail in which case it returns an error number, on success it returns 0. Whereas [pthread_self()](http://man.yolinux.com/cgi-bin/man2html?cgi_command=pthread_self) returns the thread id of the current running thread. If you want the threads to be cancelled at a particular state or of a particular type you can use [pthread_setcancelstate()](http://man.yolinux.com/cgi-bin/man2html?cgi_command=pthread_setcancelstate) and [pthread_setcanceltype(](http://man.yolinux.com/cgi-bin/man2html?cgi_command=pthread_setcanceltype)) . hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Save the handle where you create the thread.
Thread implementations are usually highly OS dependent, provide more info.

For linux(you need the handle which you saved at creation):
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html

There's probably some way to enumerate all threads of your process. But I don't think it's necessary, just keep track of your threads.

Answer (score 0):

Killing the process automatically kills the threads it has started. But to kill a particular thread get the id of pthread_create and use it in pthread_kill.
Here is an useful link:

> https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#PthreadsAPI